# How to pause (and resume) background location monitoring when low battery?

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

I'm writing a location tracking application for iOS 7.1 (iPhone) which requires to stop or pause background location monitoring when the battery is 30% and lower. The location monitoring should resume in the background when the battery improves. How can I do this? I'm using significant location change update (CLLocationManager API methods) for background location monitoring.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean how to read the battery level?  http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/02/14/reading-the-battery-level-programmatically/

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)

> If you start this service and your application is subsequently
>   terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into
>   the background if a new event arrives. In such a case, the options
>   dictionary passed to the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
>   method of your application delegate contains the key
>   UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate that your
>   application was launched because of a location event. Upon relaunch,
>   you must still configure a location manager object and call this
>   method to continue receiving location events. When you restart
>   location services, the current event is delivered to your delegate
>   immediately. In addition, the location property of your location
>   manager object is populated with the most recent location object even
>   before you start location services.

**First Step :-**

So when application launch in background then check the launch option key for `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey`.Then you will know application launch cause of location event.

> The application tracks location updates in the background, was purged,
>   and has now been relaunched. In this case, the dictionary contains a
>   key indicating that the application was relaunched because of a new
>   location event.

**Second Step :- Get battery %**

```
//This will give you the battery between 0.0 (empty) and 1.0 (100% charged)
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float batteryLevel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel];

//If you want it as a percentage, you can do this:
batteryLevel *= 100;
```

**Third Step :- Do check for application state  ( If required So)**

If application is in background then do the next step

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground
```

**Fourth Step :- Stop Monitoring Significant location change**

Apply check for battery percentage and if less than 30%, then stop monitoring location update.

If you find battery level more than 30% and location monitoring not enabled then `startMonitoringLocationUpdate`

This check can be done in `didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` and may be at the application become active OR as per your application requirement.

Hope this helps you ...!!!

Comment: After the stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges or stopUpdatingLocation is invoked how can the startUpdatingLocation  or startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges be invoked - are you saying that user should authorize location monitoring via settings?

Comment: @java_pill For that you can use a Local notification on battery level and get that event for start again that update.